# Can I define MyType that can contain only these values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have this problem: if I have, for example, these values: 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BC' - can I define  MyType that can contain only these values?

I want to do in mode that:

```
type MyType = ... ; // something
var X: MyType;
begin
  x := 'AA' ;  // is valid, 'AA' is included in X 
  X := 'SS' ;  // not valid, 'SS' not is included in X, than raise an exception.
end;
```

How can I solve it? Is there some solution directly using type data?

Comment: What about `type TMyType = (mtAA, mtAB, mtAC, mtBC)`?

Comment: Use an enumerated type  for compile time protection or a property setter for runtime protection

Comment: But not as constant, but as string for example, something as: TMytype = ('AA', 'AB','AC', 'BC') and to be sure that if X is defined as tmytype then X can assume only that value and for other value raise a exception.

Comment: @david, hello, i have thinked about it, but in my case i have string value.

Comment: If you are adamant that you cannot use an enumerated type then you'll simply have to write code that checks validity at runtime. I stand by my first comment which enumerates your two options.

Comment: @david, sorry but not understood :( if i have:  type mytype = (aa, ab, ac, bc) and define: var x: mytype then doing:  x := aa it works. But my problem is other. Me not have it, to input i have a string, for example: 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc' and x can contain only these value. if to input i give other value, i need that return a exception. I have thinked to use a array where put these value and with function get the value and check if present or less in this array of string, but i wanted know is possible in other mode without use array of string. Thanks again.

Comment: You appear to have understood me fine. We are saying just the same things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually rather simple using operator overloading.

Do

```
type
  TMyType = record
  private
    type
      TMyTypeEnum = (mtAA, mtAB, mtAC, mtBC);
    var
      FMyTypeEnum: TMyTypeEnum;
  public
    class operator Implicit(const S: string): TMyType;
    class operator Implicit(const S: TMyType): string;
  end;

implementation

class operator TMyType.Implicit(const S: string): TMyType;
begin
  if SameStr(S, 'AA') then begin result.FMyTypeEnum := mtAA; Exit; end;
  if SameStr(S, 'AB') then begin result.FMyTypeEnum := mtAB; Exit; end;
  if SameStr(S, 'AC') then begin result.FMyTypeEnum := mtAC; Exit; end;
  if SameStr(S, 'BC') then begin result.FMyTypeEnum := mtBC; Exit; end;
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid value "%s".', [S]);
end;

class operator TMyType.Implicit(const S: TMyType): string;
begin
  case S.FMyTypeEnum of
    mtAA: result := 'AA';
    mtAB: result := 'AB';
    mtAC: result := 'AC';
    mtBC: result := 'BC';
  end;
end;
```

Now you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: TMyType;
begin
  S := 'AA';                // works
  Self.Caption := S;

  S := 'DA';                // does not work, exception raised
  Self.Caption := S;
end;
```